# How to Climbed up variables in php Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
@foreach($news as $val)
  {{$val->title_en}}
@endforeach
```

like this:

```
{{$val->title_$lang}}
```

I want to use the $lang variable to get another column data (MySQL).
I need to change the language.

Comment: Please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use associative arrays instead!

Comment: Just a note -  it may be better to have one column for 'language code' eg. gb, us etc. and then in the body text have it in the language. Then you can group each language in a collection easily and just foreach through them.

Comment: Can you explain the term "climbed up variable"?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
{{ $val->{'title_'.$lang} }}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if you find it useful

Comment: My pet hate on SO is OP not accepting an answer even though the just commented on the post. I almost feel like we need a mod intervention flag for when OP comments but doesn't accept the answer..!